# I have a problem to send a data from javascript to python flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I wrote a javascript and HTML code like this (content is a list to show).

```
    <script>
        function popupForModifying() {
            let option = "width=820, height=400, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no";
            window.open("{{ url_for('modify',  content=content[2], title=content[0], category=content[4]) }}", "", option);
        }
    </script>

    <article>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="table-active">
                    <th class="col-8 text-left">{{ content[0] }}</th>
                    <th class="col-4"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">{{ content[4] }}&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        |&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ content[1] }}&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        |&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ content[3][0] }}</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-12 text-left">{{ content[2] }}</td>
                    <td class="col-0"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-light" href="javascript:popupForModifying()">수정하기</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </article>
```

And I worte python code like this.

```
@app.route('/modify', methods=['GET'])
def modify():
    title, category, content = (request.args.get(i) for i in ('title', 'category', 'content'))
    return render_template('modify_content_n.html', title=title, category=category, content=content)
```

But, except title, all variables got None.
So, I found the reason.
Finally, I got the reason but it was make me confused.
This is the reason I found.

127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2020 21:53:09] "GET /modify?title=2+입니다&content=2고요&category=데이터 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Korean is just data.
Why is 'amp;' attached?

Comment: Attached from what?

Comment: 'amp;' is followed by all '&' in the address. And the problem is that '&' is marked as '& amp;' in HTML. What can I do?